# Unexpected results using "in" with an Enum

Tags: python, enums

The following program (checked on Python 3.9 and 3.10) outputs `False`, but I expected it to output `True`:

```
import enum

class OtherTest(str, enum.Enum):
    CLIP = "clip"
    
class Test(str, enum.Enum):
    PACK = "pack"
    CLIP = OtherTest.CLIP
    
print("clip" in (Test.PACK, Test.CLIP))
```

Why is `"clip"` not in `(Test.PACK, Test.CLIP)`?

It outputs `True` if I do this instead:

```
import enum

class OtherTest(str, enum.Enum):
    CLIP = "clip"
    
class Test(str, enum.Enum):
    PACK = "pack"
    CLIP = "clip"    # Set to "clip" instead of OtherTest.CLIP
    
print("clip" in (Test.PACK, Test.CLIP))
```

I can't figure out what is going on in the first program.

Comment: If you look at the tuple you're comparing to, it prints: `(<Test.PACK: 'pack'>, <Test.CLIP: 'OtherTest.CLIP'>)`. You should probably use `StrEnum`, and/or use _actual members_ rather than strings.

Comment: In the first case, what is `Test.CLIP.value`?

Comment: @PeterWood It's... `"OtherTest.CLIP"`. Hmm...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks; I think, according to the docs, `StrEnum` wasn't added until Python 3.11, which unfortunately I can't use on this particular project for a bunch of reasons.

Comment: Using one enum's member as another enum's member's value is not a good idea -- what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @EthanFurman I'm not trying to accomplish anything; I [came across this pattern in some open source software](https://github.com/penguinolog/urwid/blob/9e1a128bf80805ee84d8cb1af5b5b5017817240d/urwid/widget/constants.py#L54) in a new release today, and [it is causing a bug](https://github.com/urwid/urwid/pull/595#issuecomment-1730345848), and while investigating why it was causing a bug I discovered this behavior.

Comment: @PeterWood The only reason I can work out for its value being `"OtherTest.CLIP"` is if at some point `str()` was used on the value to generate `Test.CLIP.value`. But I'm not sure why that would have happened.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In the software linked in my above comment, these values used to be actual strings, then were converted to enums in a recent release, which introduced at least one bug. I don't think enforcing the use of actual members would be an option, really, since it would break software that used the API that expected strings. I think what probably should have happened is the strings never should have been converted to enums in the first place, at least not without better testing.

Comment: @JasonC inheriting from `Enum` "does things" to your class definition. So, in your second example `CLIP` is not a `str` object. However, it does evaluate equal to `"clip"`. In your first example `CLIP` is not `OtherTest.CLIP` and is not a `str` object either. It does not evaluate equal to `"clip"`, but does evaluate equal to `OtherTest.CLIP`.

Comment: @JasonC: when a type is mixed-in to an enum, that type is used to generate the `.value`, so the value of `Test.CLIP` was generated by `str(OtherTest.CLIP)` (which is `"OtherTest.CLIP"`).  In Python 3.12 `StrEnum` was added, and `IntEnum` and `IntFlag` modified, so that `str(enum_member)` was the same as `str(enum_member.value)` precisely to avoid the problem you are seeing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a type is mixed in to an enum, that type is used to generate the `value`, so the value of `Test.CLIP` was generated by `str(OtherTest.CLIP)` (which is `"OtherTest.CLIP"`). In Python 3.12 `StrEnum` was added, and `IntEnum` and `IntFlag` modified, so that `str(enum_member)` was the same as `str(enum_member.value)` precisely to avoid the problem of constants converted to enums no longer working correctly as you are seeing now.

Having said that, using one enum member as the value of another enum member is not intended, and can easily cause confusion:

```py
import enum

class OtherTest(enum.StrEnum):
    CLIP = "clip"

class Test(enum.StrEnum):
    PACK = "pack"
    CLIP = OtherTest.CLIP

"clip" in (Test.PACK, Test.CLIP))
# True
Test.CLIP == OtherTest.CLIP
# True
Test.CLIP is OtherTest.CLIP  # given the above definition, one could expect this to be True
# False
```

---

**N.B.**  `IntEnum`, `IntFlag`, and `StrEnum` are meant to be used as drop-in replacements for existing constants (the big difference being the behavior of `str(member)`); to get the same `str` behavior in a custom mixed enum, inherit from `ReprEnum`:

```py
import enum

class MyFloat(float, enum.Enum):
    ONE = 1.0

class ReprFloat(float, enum.ReprEnum):
    ONE = 1.0

MyFloat.ONE, str(MyFloat.ONE)
# (<MyFloat.ONE: 1.0>, 'MyFloat.ONE')

ReprFloat.ONE, str(ReprFloat.ONE)
# (<ReprFloat.ONE: 1.0>, '1.0')
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.