# How to statically protect against str == enum comparisons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-3.7

More often than not, I make the following mistake:

```
import enum

class StatusValues(enum.Enum):
    one = "one"
    two = "two"

def status_is_one(status: str):
    return status == StatusValues.one
```

String will never be an enum class. The problem is that it should be `StatusValues.one.value`.

Is there a `strcmp(status, StatusValues.one)`-ish function so that my pyright will error on the line that I am comparing string with a class? Is there a good way to protect against such mistakes?

Comment: have you tried using a string enum? `class StatusValues(str, enum.Enum):` (or `enum.StrEnum` in Python 3.11+).
With string enums, comparison will succeed just fine, e.g. `status = "one"; status == StatusValues.one`

Comment: Wow, that is fantastic to know. I have to be compatible with python 3.7.

Comment: Then define enum by mixing `str` into it. :)
OK good, I udnerstood the problem correctly, let me write a more elaborate answer shortly

Comment: I've never used pyright but the "reportUnnecessaryComparison" setting sounds like it is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this can be a gotcha: by default we cannot directly compare strings with enum members:

```py
>>> status = "two"
>>> status == StatusValues.two
False
```

One has to remember to compare a string to the enum member's `.value`, which is also kind of verbose:

```py
>>> "two" == StatusValues.two.value
True
```

Fortunately, there is a solution, which is even [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/enum.html#others), but it used to be (pre- Python 3.11) in a section that was somewhat easy to miss (IMHO). We can mix in a type of enum members:

```py
class IntEnum(int, Enum):
    pass
```

> This demonstrates how similar derived enumerations can be defined; for example a StrEnum that mixes in `str` instead of `int`.

The solution is therefore to define an enum with a `str` base class:

```py
class StatusValues(str, Enum):
    one = "one"
    two = "two"

>>> status = "two"
>>> status == StatusValues.two  # no .value
True
```

In Python 3.11+ [StrEnum](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum) is already included in the `enum` module, but you mentioned that you still need to support Python 3.7.

Comment: Note these mix-in enums don't always behave predictably: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77153859/3001761

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing that!
Fortunately, it seems like an edge case that is discouraged by the very Enum author himself, but nevertheless good to know about it.

Comment: This is a very useful answer. I was not aware, despite reading docs many times, that you can inherit from str and Enum at the same time to achieve this behavior. It was very easy to do 3.7 portability class that look like `class MyStrEnum(str, Enum): def _generate_next_value_(name, *args): return name`

Comment: Indeed, and this is _exactly_ what I used in several projects ([example](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/54a77694afcd80be4ba469c6ebb7ca8be112b04e/google/cloud/bigquery/magics/line_arg_parser/lexer.py#L94-L98)).

Such a class even spares us the repetition when typing enum members' values (e.g. `foo = 'foo'`), we can just say `foo = enum.auto()`, protecting us against typos in string values.